# The Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}[\Bbb{R}^d]$ is generated by the compact sets of $\Bbb{R}^d$ - proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

I am reading [Terrence Tao's book on measure theory](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf).

On page 103, there is an exercise to prove that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}[\Bbb{R}^d]$ is generated by the compact sets of $\Bbb{R}^d$.

My attempt at a solution:

$\mathcal{B}[\Bbb{R}^d]$ is generated by the open sets, or equivalently by the closed sets.

By the Heine-Borel Theorem, a set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. Thus, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the compact sets is contained in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the closed sets.

I'm not sure about the other containment. Each unbounded closed set is an infinite union of bounded closed sets. Therefore, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the compact sets contains every closed set, and is therefore generated by the closed sets.

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: You need that each closed set is a **countable** union of closed bounded sets.

Comment: You've got the right idea, but the argument is not 100% clean. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the *smallest* $\sigma$-algebra containing the closed sets. Since closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$ are *countable* union of compact sets, what do you conclude?

Comment: @PedroM. That every closed set is in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the compact sets?

Comment: Good. And since the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the smallest one that contains the closed sets...

Comment: @PedroM. Got it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof that $\mathcal{B}[\Bbb{R}^d]$ is contained in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the compact sets in $\Bbb{R}^d$ is:

Every closed set is the countable union of closed bounded (and thus, by Heine-Borel, compact) sets. So every closed set is in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the compact sets, and since $\mathcal{B}[\Bbb{R}^d]$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all of the closed sets, $\mathcal{B}[\mathbb{R}^d]$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the compact sets.